# Cgroup rules engine (cgrulesengd) misses child processes

Tags: ssh, cgroups

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and 14.04 machines and am trying to keep users from using Nvidia GPUs in ssh sessions with cgroup rules engine.

My current `/etc/cgconfig.conf` looks like:

```
group nogpu {
  devices {
    devices.allow = "a *:* rwm";
    devices.deny = "c 195:* rwm";
  }
}
```

and `/etc/cgrules.conf` is like:

```
@groupname:sshd devices nogpu
```

The problem is that `cgrulesengd` often misses `sshd`s' child processes. When that happens, `tasks` in the `nogpu` cgroup contains the `sshd` processes but not their child (shell) processes.

I read [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/pdf/Resource_Management_Guide/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux-6-Resource_Management_Guide-en-US.pdf) that quickly spawned child processes might be in wrong groups, but it's too frequent on many machines.
Adding a rule for `root:sshd` doesn't help.

Is there any way to make `cgrulesengd` capture the child processes more solidly?

Thank you.

**ADD:** My current workaround is to use `ForceCommand` in `sshd_config` to wrap `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` or the shell and add itself to the cgroup (I didn't use `pam_exec.so` since it cannot be the parent process of the shell process). But I still want to know if `cgrulesengd` itself can be more consistent.

Comment: Please detail your workaround for people having the same problem, until we have a solution here.